# Why is the minimum of two subharmonic functions not subharmonic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a counterexample of two one-dimensional subharmonic functions, where the minimum is not subharmonic?
And why it works for the maximum, but not for the minimum ?

Comment: Check the functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto-x$. Also, just as maximum works for **sub**harmonic, minimum works for **super** harmonic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that, maybe you can explain it to me. $ min\{x,-x\} = - |x| $ and this should be a harmonic function , or am I wrong ?

Comment: No, $-|x|$ is not harmonic.

Comment: Thank you ! You are right, it is neither harmonic nor subharmonic with the mean value property.